# Are there classes with different sizes?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Are there classes with different sizes ? I will put a precise statement of my question below:

Are there two well formed formulas $P,Q$  each with one free variable such that there is no well formed formula $F$ with two free variables such that the following holds:

1)$\forall x \forall y [F(x,y)\rightarrow[P(x)\land Q(y)]]$

2)$\forall x\exists!y F(x,y)$ (Analogue of the condition imposed on a relation to make it a function)

3)$\forall y \exists!x F(x,y)$ (Analogue of the condition imposed on a function to make it injective and surjective)

(The well formed formulas $P,Q,F$ are expressions of the language $L_1Set$)

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trivially if we allow to consider that sets are classes. But let's assume that you really just meant proper classes.

If we only assume $\sf ZFC$, then it is consistent that yes, and consistent that no.

- If one assumes that global choice holds, then there is a definable bijection between the class of ordinals and the universe. It follows that there is a bijection between any two proper classes.

  For example if $V=L$ holds, or even $V=HOD$, or $V=L[x]$, all those imply that there is a definable (perhaps with parameters) bijection like that.
- On the other hand, it is also consistent that there is no bijection between the class of ordinals and the universe. If use class forcing, an Easton product of forcing which add two sets to every regular cardinal, then we can prove that the universe of the extension cannot be linearly ordered (in $\sf ZFC$), let alone well-ordered.

Comment: Hi. I have a  probably trivial question:Why is the question of my post trivial if we allow to consider that sets are classes ?

Comment: Because there are trivially sets with different cardinalities, and no set has the cardinality of the universe...

Comment: Wouldn't this choice of $P,Q$ work (I am not sure if it works) let $a,b$ be two sets of different cardinality. Then set $P(x)$ to be $x\in a$ and $Q(x)$ to be $x\in b$...

Comment: Yes, but if you want to avoid using parameters (the sets $a$ and $b$) you can use something which is definable, like the natural numbers and its power set.

Comment: Hence, the suggestion of my last comment still works even if we don't allow the collection of all sets to be a class, no ?

Comment: Now what if I impose the following condition on $P,Q$. There is not set $a$ such that $\forall x [x\in a \iff P(x)]$ and there is not set $b$ such that $\forall x [x\in b \iff Q(x)]$

Comment: OK. Thanks Asaf. I realized that your first bullet answers my question. I did not understand the rest of the bullets since they are beyond my level. I am studying logic now, and might know enough to understand what you said +1

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your question, but my point is this if you assume $\sf ZFC$ then it is provably the case that there are classes which are sets and have different cardinality; if you therefore limit yourself to the case of proper classes then it is consistent that every two proper classes have the same cardinality (i.e. there is a definable bijection between them), and it is consistent that there are no definable bijections between the class of ordinals and the class of all sets.

Comment: OK now I understood more. Thanks for the clarification. (You understood the question right)